# How to use springdoc with @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE) and @RequestParam

Tags: migration, springfox, springdoc

I'm upgrading a project from SpringFox to SpringDoc v1.6.12 and I struggle to make the new code work for the following method of my RestController:

```
@PostMapping(path = TASK_MAPPING_PATH, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> loadTask(
      @RequestParam String applicationId,
      @RequestParam String businessId,
      @RequestParam boolean directLink
) {[...]}
```

The particularity of this method is that it should encode its parameters in the body since the Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded is used.

But when I browse the url *https://localhost:8443/v3/api-docs*, the generated code is the following:

```
"/api/enrolment/task" : {
      "post" : {
        "operationId" : "loadTask",
        "parameters" : [ {
          "in" : "query",
          "name" : "applicationId",
          "required" : true,
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }, {
          "in" : "query",
          "name" : "businessId",
          "required" : true,
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }, {
          "in" : "query",
          "name" : "directLink",
          "required" : true,
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          }
        } ],
        "responses" : {
          [...]
        },
        "summary" : [...],
        "tags" : [...]
      }
    },
```

All of the  `applicationId`, `businessId` and `directLink` parameters are passed in the URL instead of the request body as expected.

I would have expected the following openApi definition instead:

```
"/api/enrolment/task" : {
      "post" : {
        "operationId" : "loadTask",
        "requestBody" : {
          "content" : {
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" : {
              "schema" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                  "applicationId" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "businessId" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "directLink" : {
                    "type" : "boolean"
                  }
                },
                "required" : [ "applicationId", "businessId", "directLink" ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses" : {
          [...]
        },
        "summary" : [...],
        "tags" : [...]
      }
    },
```

Does anyone ever had the same issue ?
Does anyone knows the solution to my problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: The issue isn't with Springdoc but your code. I'm not too familiar with Springfox (and why it worked previously) but the output you're getting in Springdoc is correct. If you want something to be read from request body, you should wrap that data in a POJO and use `@RequestBody MyPojo body` as a parameter to your method. `@RequestParam` always means query parameters irrespective of the HTTP verb.

Comment: The documentation of @RequestParam says otherwise: In Spring MVC, "request parameters" map to query parameters, form data,and parts in multipart requests. This is because the Servlet API combines query parameters and form data into a single map called "parameters", and that includes automatic parsing of the request body.